# Verifying the arguments of subsequent calls to the same method in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class A that has to make two subsequent calls to a method of its dependency B that takes a collection as an argument:

```
class A{
    private B myDependency;

    public myClassMethod() {
    // ... on more than one occasion calls myDependency.dependencyMehtod(someColleciton);
    }
}

class B{
    public void dependencyMehtod(Collection<Something> input)
}
```

I would like to write a unit test for class A (preferably using Mockito) that verifies that
the dependency method was called exactly a given number of times and also verify the size of the input Collection at each subsequent invocation (the size of the argument varies between calls).
How would I do that?

I tried using

```
myAObject.myClassMethod();

verify(myMockOfB).dependencyMehtod((Collection<Something>) argThat(hasSize(3));  //I expect a size of 3 on the first call
verify(myMockOfB).dependencyMehtod((Collection<Something>) argThat(hasSize(1));  //I expect a size of 1 on the second call
```

However, I get an error message from Mockito that A collection of size 1 was found where a collection of size 3 was expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#6. Almost everything about Mockito is described on this page, with examples and everything. Read it all.

Comment: Looks to be a dupe of an answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573399/how-to-verify-invocations-of-the-same-mock-method-with-the-same-argument-that-ch

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArgumentCaptor`. Here is an example:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Collection<Something>> valuesArgument;

/*
...
 */

@Test
public void test() {
    /*
    ...
     */

    // verify the number of calls
    verify(myMockOfB, times(2)).dependencyMehtod(valuesArgument.capture());

    // first call
    assertEquals(3, valuesArgument.getAllValues().get(0).size());

    // second call
    assertEquals(1, valuesArgument.getAllValues().get(1).size());
}
```

Comment: Good, but there is a problem: if I keep passing the same collection to the method at each invocation, I would only have the last state in the argument captor. Basically, it just keeps a reference to the argument object, it tells me nothing of the state of this object at the time of the method invocation. And Collections' contents do tend to change over time :)

Comment: You're right. This only works with distinct collections. I didn't account for multiple calls with the same collection.