# How to verify invocations of the same mock method with the same argument that changes state between invocations in mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following code to be unit tested:

```
public void foo() {
    Entity entity = //...
    persistence.save(entity);
    entity.setDate(new Date());
    persistence.save(entity);
}
```

I would like to verify that on the first invocation of `persistence.save` `entity.getDate()` returns `null`.

Therefore I'm unable to use `Mockito.verify(/*...*/)` because at that time the method `foo` already completed and `entity.setDate(Date)` was called.

So I think I need to do verifications of invocations already at the time the invocations happen. How do I do this using Mockito?

Comment: Cancel that... Didn't notice this was implementation :-)

Comment: To clarify, it sounds like you want to basically check that date is null after the first save? Sounds like you'd basically be injecting single line of code after the first save. I'm not sure if that's possible. If `persistence` is what's being mocked, you could mock the save method to fail if it's null.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider `persistence` is the object that is being mocked. But I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Looking at my comment, I can see I didn't explain it well, but it appears you figured it out. More specifically, what I meant was, when you call `save()` that is a mocked method. If the first time it's called date is not null, you fail (You could throw a RuntimeException, for instance). The second time through, it should be set to not fail. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created the following `Answer` implementation:

```
public class CapturingAnswer<T, R> implements Answer<T> {

    private final Function<InvocationOnMock, R> capturingFunction;

    private final List<R> capturedValues = new ArrayList<R>();

    public CapturingAnswer(final Function<InvocationOnMock, R> capturingFunction) {
        super();
        this.capturingFunction = capturingFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public T answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        capturedValues.add(capturingFunction.apply(invocation));
        return null;
    }

    public List<R> getCapturedValues() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(capturedValues);
    }

}
```

This answer captures properties of the invocations being made. The `capturedValues` can then be used for simple assertions. The implementation uses Java 8 API. If that is not available one would need to use an interface that is able to convert the `InvocationOnMock` to the captured value. The usage in the testcase is like this:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    CapturingAnswer<Void,Date> captureDates = new CapturingAnswer<>(this::getEntityDate)
    Mockito.doAnswer(captureDates).when(persistence).save(Mockito.any(Entity.class));

    service.foo();

    Assert.assertNull(captureDates.getCapturedValues().get(0));
}

private Date getEntityDate(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    Entity entity = (Entity)invocation.getArguments()[0];
    return entity.getDate();
}
```

The capturing that is done by the presented `Answer` implementation can't be achieved with Mockitos `ArgumentCaptor` because this is only used after the invocation of the method under test.

Answer (score 1):

In my original comment, this was the answer I had in mind.

The class to be mocked:

```
class MockedClass{
    void save(SomeBean sb){
        //doStuff
    }
}
```

The class we'll need to verify the Date object is null.

```
class SomeBean{
    Date date;

    Date getDate(){return date;}

    void setDate(Date date){this.date=date;}
}
```

The class under test:

```
class TestClass{
    MockedClass mc;

    TestClass(MockedClass mc){this.mc = mc;}

    void doWork(){
        SomeBean sb = new SomeBean();
        mc.save(sb);
        sb.setDate(new Date());
        mc.save(sb);
    }
}
```

And the test case:

```
@Test
public void testAnswer(){
    MockedClass mc = Mockito.mock(MockedClass.class);
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>(){
        boolean checkDate = true;
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            SomeBean sb = (SomeBean) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            if(checkDate && sb.getDate() != null){
                throw new NullPointerException(); //Or a more meaningful exception
            }
            checkDate = false;
            return null;
        }}).when(mc).save(Mockito.any(SomeBean.class));;

    TestClass tc =  new TestClass(mc);
    tc.doWork();
}
```

The first time through this `Answer` (The term I should have used in my original comment), this will throw an exception and fail the test case if date is not null. The second time through, `checkDate` will be false, so the check will not be performed.

Comment: When using custom answer implementations that throw an exception, be sure that the unit under test doesn't handle such exceptions.